# File sharing between OS X and RPi: Finder won't notice changes

Tags: macos, file-sharing

I set up file sharing between the Raspberry Pi and a Mac following [this guide](http://4dc5.com/2012/06/12/setting-up-vnc-on-raspberry-pi-for-mac-access/).  Most things work well: I can access the Pi from OS X's Finder.  If new files are added on the Pi, they appear in the Finder window right away.  However, if existing files are modified on the Pi, the Mac won't notice this, and will still show the old, cached version.  How can I get the Finder to update when existing files are changed on the Pi?

---

Example for clarification:

Doing

```
touch newFile
```

on the Pi will cause `newFile` to appear in the Finder window on the Mac.  Now after changing this file,

```
echo something > newFile
```

the Mac still sees `newFile` as empty.  Now creating another file

```
touch secondFile
```

will cause the Mac to sync to the Pi and show both the empty `secondFile` and the updated contents of `newFile`.

I'm looking for a solution that will let the Mac pick up changes to existing files as well.

Comment: do you use samba? try afp/netatalk

Comment: @Gotschi I did link to the guide I used to set it up, which has complete details, and uses afp.